# Magento 2: Captcha issue on Page load

Tags: magento2.2, captcha

I'm using Magento 2.2.7, I enabled Captcha in **Store->Configuration->Customer configuration->Captcha** Enabled for **create user** **and forgot password** forms.

Captcha always displaying incorrect even I used correct letters. After I clicked reload captcha and try again it is working.

I know it is fixed in Magento 2.3.X. But I need to fix in Magento 2.2.7 version. Is there any way to fix this without using jQuery trigger click event.

Comment: You can upgrade the Captcha to the latest version to fix this issue.

Comment: Ahh.....Is it possible to upgrade captcha module alone?

Comment: Yes, it is possible via composer.

Comment: Will try and let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the MSP Recaptcha to the latest version 2.1.2 by running the following command in the terminal.

```
composer require msp/recaptcha:2.1.2
php bin/magento s:up
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Is it compatible with Magento 2.2.7?

Comment: Yes, you can try it on your local.

Comment: I need to explore what the exact issue is....pls let me know

Comment: you can compare the extension files for old and newer version to check the issue.

Comment: I can't find the fix in latest module-captcha extension....If you aware of it please share the explainations

Comment: I've fixed the issue by upgrading the extension to the latest version. I've not dug into the code for checking the issue as limited time. Please share if the extension upgrade fixes the issue.

Comment: Is this solution helped you to find your fix?

Comment: Yes sorry i forgot to accept